# How to use a custom Bulma Theme in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bulma

How can I use a theme from Bulmaswatch in my rails app? I'm currently using the bulma-rails gem. Bulmaswatch recommend using their CDN but how to get it work with the asset pipeline? What's the simplest easier way to get it done?

Answer (score 0):

(Supposition is you have routes, controllers, views sorted) 
Add the bulma gem (cdn not needed)
Add any number of Boostrap gems that play well with sass
Bundle 
Add @import "bulma"; into application file
Restart the server

Comment: Yes, I'm already using Bulma on my app but I want to use a custom theme from Bulmaswatch.

Comment: custom theme is just a paid them, follow the above process

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the easiest way is:
Under app/assets/stylesheets delete application.css and create a new file called application.css.scss

Then in that file copy paste the code from your favorite theme on bulmaswatch.

There you  go, you've got a unique theme working in bulma.

This question is somewhat similar to: [How to customize bulma variables in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44347593/how-to-customize-bulma-variables-in-rails)